# Pointers, Arrays, Strings and Malloc in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I'm currently learning about strings, pointers and arrays in C. I tried to write a program where an array holds three pointers to string addresses. It all seems to work but the program behaves strangely.

Here's the code:

```
char** getUserDetails()
    {

    char* host = "localhost";

    char* username = "root";

    char* password = "mypassword";

    // create array for holding pointers to strings

    char *userDetailsHolder[3];

    userDetailsHolder[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(host));   
    strcpy(userDetailsHolder[0], host);

    userDetailsHolder[1] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(username));
    strcpy(userDetailsHolder[1], username);

        userDetailsHolder[2] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(password));
        strcpy(userDetailsHolder[2], password);

        return userDetailsHolder;
    }

    int main()
    {

    char** userDetails = getUserDetails();

    printf("Host: %s\nUsername: %s\nPassword: %s\n", userDetails[0], userDetails[1], userDetails[2]);

    printf("Host: %s\nUsername: %s\nPassword: %s\n", userDetails[0], userDetails[1], userDetails[2]);

            return 0;
    }
```

**Output: The output indicates that something went terribly wrong**

```
Host: localhost
Username: root
Password: mypassword
Host: root
Username: localhost
Password: Host: %s
Username: %s
Password: %s
```

---

The first `printf` seems to work, but the second has the wrong data in it. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning a pointer to an array which resides on the stack. `userDetailsHolder` is allocated on the stack and is not available after the function returns.

You could use `malloc` once more to allocate the array itself, and then it will be available after the function returns.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I have never done that though. I tried to add the following code:

Comment: char** arrayOnStack = malloc(sizeof(userDetailsHolder));
 arrayOnStack = userDetailsHolder;
 
 return arrayOnStack;

Comment: The new code would be `char **userDetailsHolder = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3)`

Comment: Hey thanks, works perfectly. Is there some kind of rule you use to keep track of all the de-referencing? As a beginner I find it quite confusing to know at which level I'm at..

Comment: It's quite simple when you get it... Every asterisk in the declaration of a pointer corresponds to one dereferencing. For example, if you have declared an `int *****a`, the expression `**a` will yield a pointer of type `int ***`.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm still always trying to speak to myself what the code actually means. We have a pointer to a pointer to a character..

Answer (score 3):

Also, remember to allocate `strlen(s)+1` bytes for strings.  C strings are terminated with the zero byte and you need to make sure there's space for it.

Comment: Thanks, I already added it to the code: userDetailsHolder[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(host)+1));