# How do strings and bits work in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, sizeof, bit

I have a two part question:

1. Understand output from `sizeof`
2. Understand how strings are stored in variables (e.g. bits and ram)

### Question 1

I'm trying to understand the output from the following piece of C code.

```
printf("a: %ld\n", sizeof("a")); // 2
printf("abc: %ld\n", sizeof("abc")); // 4
```

It always seems to be one larger than the actual number of characters specified.

The docs suggest that the returned value represents the size of the object (in this case a string) in bytes. So if the size of `a` gives us back `2` bytes, then I'm curious how `a` represents 16 bits of information.

If I look at the binary representation of the ASCII character `a` I can see it is `01100001`. But that's only showing 3 bits out of 1 byte being used.

### Question 2

Also, how do large strings get stored into a variable in C? Am I right in thinking that they have to be stored within an array, like so:

```
char my_string[5] = "hello";
```

Interestingly when I have some code like:

```
char my_string = "hello";
printf("my_string: %s\n", my_string);
```

I get two compiler errors:

```
- incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'char' with an expression of type 'char [6]'
- format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char'
```

...which I don't understand. Firstly it states the type is presumed to be a size of `[6]` when there's only 5 characters. Secondly the mention of a pointer here seems odd to me? Why does `printf` expect a pointer and why does not specifying the length of the variable/array result in a pointer to integer error?

By the way I seemingly can set the length of the variable/array to 5 rather than 6 and it'll work as I'd expect it to `char my_string[5] = "hello";`.

I'm probably just missing something very basic/fundamental about how bits and strings work in C.

Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: sizeof return a size_t, aka uintmax_t. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family) to know the good flag. The string in C are finish by a '\0', so "a" == {'a', '\0'} so two char. `char my_string[5] = "hello";` is not valide you have no space for '\0'.

Comment: Post two separate questions.

Comment: @Stargateur: `size_t` is not synonymous with `uintmax_t`. For example, on many 32-bit platforms, `size_t` is 32-bit, but `uintmax_t` may represent 64-bit integers (`unsigned long long`).

Comment: @dreamlax nope, uintmax_t is the max integer provider by the implementation. So in 32 bit, uintmax_t => uint32_t. [doc](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h). The purpose of size_t is to handle a size, so a unsigned integer. uintmax_t  is perfect to represent that.

Comment: `char my_string[5] = "hello";` will likely lead to buffer overruns. As, @JohnBode points out his his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40705260/2226988), let the compiler figure out what the size of the array should be.

Comment: @Stargateur: uintmax_t is usually set to `unsigned long long`, which even on 32-bit platforms represents a 64 bit integer, but `size_t` on 32-bit platforms is usually set to `unsigned long`, therefore they are **not synonymous**.

Comment: @Stargateur: It even mentions in the documentation that you linked to that the *minimum* required range for `size_t` is only [0-65535], whereas the minimum required range for `uintmax_t` is [0-2^64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the question is due to the way strings are stored in C. Strings in C are nothing more than a series of characters (`char`) with a `\0` added at the end, which is the reason you're seeing a +1 when you do sizeof. Notice in your second part if you were to say `char my_string[4] = "hello";` you'd also get a compiler error saying there wasn't enough size for this string. That's also related to this.

Now onto the second part, strings themselves are a series of characters. However, you don't store every character by themselves in a variable. You instead have a **pointer** to these series of characters that will allow you to access them from some part of memory. Additional information regarding pointers and strings in C can be found here: [Pointer to a String in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168771/pointer-to-a-string-in-c)

Comment: So just to be clear, does even a single character within a string `char x[2] = "a"` still create a variable that is assigned a pointer to the underlying array (x is assigned a pointer to `["a", "\0"]`)?

Comment: Actually answered my own question there (doh), when I realised I'd need an array because of the null terminator

Answer (score 1):

In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values followed by a zero valued terminator.  For example, the string `"hello"` is the sequence of character values `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 }`<sup>1</sup>.  Strings (including string literals) are *stored* as arrays of `char` (or `wchar_t` for wide-character strings). To account for the terminator, the size of the array must always be one greater than the number of characters in the string:

```
char greeting[6] = "hello";
```

The storage for `greeting` will look like

```
          +---+
greeting: |'h'| greeting[0]
          +---+
          |'e'| greeting[1]
          +---+
          |'l'| greeting[2]
          +---+
          |'l'| greeting[3]
          +---+
          |'o'| greeting[4]
          +---+
          | 0 | greeting[5]
          +---+
```

Storage for a string literal is largely the same<sup>2</sup>:

```
          +---+
 "hello": |'h'| "hello"[0]
          +---+
          |'e'| "hello"[1]
          +---+
          |'l'| "hello"[2]
          +---+
          |'l'| "hello"[3]
          +---+
          |'o'| "hello"[4]
          +---+
          | 0 | "hello"[5]
          +---+
```

Yes, you can apply the subscript operator `[]` to a string literal just like any other array expression.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "`N`-element of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  So, the string literal `"hello"` is an expression of type "6-element array of `char`".  If I pass that literal as an argument to a function like

```
printf( "%s\n", "hello" );
```

then both of the string literal *expressions* `"%s"` and `"hello"` are converted from "4-element array of `char`"<sup>3</sup> and "6-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", so what `printf` receives are pointer values, not array values.

You've already seen two exceptions to the conversion rule.  You saw it in your code when you used the `sizeof` operator and got a value one more than you expected.  `sizeof` evaluates to the number of bytes required to store the operand.  Because of the zero terminator, it takes N+1 bytes to store an N-character string.

The second exception is the declaration of the `greeting` array above; since I'm using the string literal to initialize the array, the literal is not converted to a pointer value first.  Note the you can write that declaration as

```
char greeting[] = "hello";
```

In that case, the size of the array is taken from the size of the initializer.

The third exception occurs when the array expression is the operand of the unary `&` operator.  Instead of evaluating to a pointer to a pointer to `char` (`char **`), the expression `&greeting` evaluates to type "pointer to *6-element array of* `char`", or `char (*)[6]`.

The *length* of a string is the number of characters before to zero terminator.  All the standard library functions that deal with strings expect to see that terminator.  The *size* of the array to store that string must be *at least* one greater than the maximum length of the string you intend to store.

---

1. Sometimes you'll see people write `'\0'` instead of a naked `0` to represent a string terminator; they mean the same thing.

   Storage for string literals is allocated at program startup and held until the program terminates.  String literals may be stored in a read-only memory segment; attempting to modify the contents of a string literal results in undefined behavior.

   `'\n'` counts as a single character.